# Elements of a DockPanel that share the same scrollbar?

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollview, dockpanel

Here is the code I have :

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" CanContentScroll="True">
      <DockPanel>
           <TreeView x:Name="tView" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
               [...]
           </TreeView>

           <TreeView Name="pluginsView" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
               [...]
           </TreeView>
      </DockPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I HAVE to define 2 TreeViews. There are in the same "area" (in mean same [Row, Column]) so I had to use a Panel. I used a StackPanel but the display was not what I wanted.
I used the ScrollViewer so that I get a common scrollbar for the 2 TreeViews when they don't vertically fit the space of the "area".

The problem I have is horizontally. When 1 of my 2 TreeView is too "large", I got a scrollbar that appears but only for the TreeView that is too large, so when I scroll, only one of my TreeView moves horizontally. What I want is that when I scroll, both of my TreeView move horizontally.

I don't know if it's clear enough, I can upload screenshots if it's not clear !

I tried this code too, but it doesn't work too :

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" CanContentScroll="True">
      <Grid Grid.Row="2">
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <TreeView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="tView" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
               [...]
           </TreeView>

           <TreeView Grid.Row="1" Name="pluginsView" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
               [...]
           </TreeView>
      </DockPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

but I got the EXACT same problem.. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like it is using the TreeView's internal `ScrollViewer` to scroll the content, not the outer `ScrollViewer`.

Usually this is because the content inside the `ScrollViewer` is limited in size in some way, so make sure you aren't limiting the size of the `TreeView` or it's parent panel in any way. This would include Vertical/Horizonal Aligment being set to Stretch.

Here's an example that works to scroll smoothly in both directions. I was a little surprised that I had to set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` in the `<ScrollViewer>` tag to make the Horizontal ScrollBar show up.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Height="100" Width="100">
    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <DockPanel>
            <Rectangle Height="75" Width="150" Fill="Red" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
            <Rectangle Height="75" Width="150" Fill="Blue" />
        </DockPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

Comment: I was using a StackPanel but the thing is that with a StackPanel, the vertical scrollbar is brutal (not smooth). It only gives me a 2 positions scrollbar that can display The 1st or the 2nd TreeView

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne Try wrapping your DockPanel or Grid in the StackPanel then. It should give you the best of both worlds :)

Comment: I think I just tried every possible wrapping and either I haven't any scrollbar or I got "buggy" scrollbars that only horizontally each TreeView independantly :(

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne I see what you mean about the jumpy ScrollBar when using a StackPanel. I updated my example to something that works in a test environment, so just adjust it to use your controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the horizontal `ScrollViewer` of the trees. This way the wrapping `ScrollViewer` will need to open.

**XAML:**

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" CanContentScroll="True">
      <Grid>
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="*" />
               <RowDefinition Height="*" />
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <TreeView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="tView" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
               [...]
           </TreeView>

           <TreeView Grid.Row="1" Name="pluginsView" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
               [...]
           </TreeView>
      </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: When i'm reducting the area to an extreme point, no scrollbar appears with your code :(
It hides the wrong scrollbar that was appearing (which is a very good thing) and I haven't got any scrollbar in the end :(

Answer (score 0):

After hours of tests, here is what worked for me :

```
 <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
     <DockPanel ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <TreeView x:Name="tView" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                [...]
            </TreeView>

            <TreeView Name="pluginsView" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                [...]
            </TreeView>
      </DockPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
```

For this to work you HAVE TO disable the visibility of TreeViews AND the Grid, AND you have to use HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" on the ScrollViewer !